# NextJS this.props + React Toast Notification

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a react application with SSR using NextJS and   [React Toast Notifications](https://github.com/jossmac/react-toast-notifications). The package requires I wrap my components with an HOC.

```
export default withToastManager(developersEdit);
```

But wrapping it with an HOC doesn't allow me to access NextJS this.props anymore. How can I still use NextJS props in my app?

I have tried exporting with a spread operator

```
export default withToastManager(developersEdit ...this.props);
```

But that didn't work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withToastManager } from 'react-toast-notifications';
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

class developersEdit extends Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backgroundImg: 'https://'+this.props.environment.API_URL+'.xyz.com/'+this.props.currentDeveloper.developer_logo,
    }
  }


  static async getInitialProps (context) {

    const { slug } = context.query;
    const {publicRuntimeConfig} = getConfig()

    const resDeveloper = await fetch(`https://${publicRuntimeConfig.API_URL}.xyz.com/api/showdeveloper/${slug}`)
    const developer = await resDeveloper.json()

    console.log(developer);
    return {
        currentDeveloper: developer.data,
        environment: publicRuntimeConfig,
        slug: slug
    }

  }
}

                ......

export default withToastManager(developersEdit);
```

I want to be able to use this.props and still keep the notification package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement getInitialProps() and render() methods in your HOC like this example:

```
export default function withToastManager(WrappedComponent, options = {}) {

    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
            const getInitialProps = WrappedComponent.getInitialProps;
            let data = {};
            if (ctx.req) {
                // server side code
                data = ctx.req.session.data; 
            } else {
                // client side code        
                data = ctx.data;
            }

            let props = {};
            if (getInitialProps) {
                props = await getInitialProps({...ctx, ...data});
            }

            return props;
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
    };
}
```

Hope it helps you.